# What's the fastest way to generate 10M UUID4s in Python

Tags: python, uuid

I need to generate a large number of UUIDs (v4).

For a baseline, the following code takes about ~60 seconds

```
import uuid
a = [uuid.uuid4() for x in range(10000000)]
```

I've tried a few different things (a few different UUID libraries but all of them seem to be unmaintained or not compatible with python 3.9)

I've also tried using some kind of multithreaded code but if anything I always end up with slower performance than the baseline.

This seems like something that should be able to be done faster than a minute - but maybe I'm just not understanding some underlying concept of how UUID's are generated?

Comment: That’s 166K+ UUIDs per second.  Seems pretty fast to me … What’s the rationale for needing a speed increase?  Perhaps implementing directly in C, *might* give some marginal gain.

Comment: It basically takes 16 bytes from urandom and wraps them in a UUID object. There's not much to optimize.

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: It's seeding a dataframe (modin) that I'm then using for a synthetic data generation script. It just seemed slow relative to the functions I was running on the dataframe once it was created but maybe my expectations were just unreasonable.

Comment: oddly enough this takes only 20 seconds on my scratch laptop.

Comment: I don't understand what that means, but do you really need UUIDs for that? Or just some random data?

Comment: @KellyBundy - Random data it’s guaranteed to be unique.  If Chris requires unique values, then UUID4 would be a way to go.

Comment: @S3DEV I think you have a typo in your first sentence, I can't make sense of it. And as far as I can see, Klaus is right - it just takes 16 bytes from urandom and wraps them in a UUID object. With a bunch of extra work, but not guaranteeing uniqueness. So purely taking 16 bytes from urandom would be just as good, and in my tests it was a lot faster. And getting all data from urandom at once and splitting it into chunks of 16 bytes was even faster. Do you disagree that it's just as random/unique as the UUID4 way?

Comment: @KellyBundy - My apologies.  Should say “random data isn’t guaranteed to be unique”.   However, I was mistaken in that I mixed up UUID1 and UUID4 for guaranteed uniqueness.  UUID1 is, if certain parameters are used, as it can consider global MAC and datetime.  Whereas the comments are absolutely correct in that UUID4 is ‘simply’ random 16 bytes.

Comment: @S3DEV Oh, actually I just saw that the UUIDs encode version/variant inside the 16 bytes, and only use 122 random bits instead of 128. So for randomness/uniqueness, pure random 16 bytes would actually be *better*.